# After refactor package name everything is gone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After easy steps of refactoring and changing the name of package my android studio destroy package folders. Did someone faced that problem?

[image]

And error is

```
Error:(10, 40) error: package com.example.android.shoppinglist does not exist
    Error:(31, 35) error: package R does not exist
```

Comment: You need to check the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`, I've faced something like this more than once. Try File->Invalidate Cache and Restart as the last resort.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך i have done restart. Now everything crashes and projects which were working ok now doesn't work

Comment: What is the error? The project needs to rebuild again after invalidating the cache.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך now it doesn't see some of files. On first build it give error on png file that everything in drawable has to end .xml or .png but that default picture IS .png

Comment: take a look at the your drawable folder. Manually check the file, maybe it got corrupted. Did you use Windows?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך my main goal was change the name of package. But it is not changing. After refactor it gives million of errors and package have the same name as it was

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך yes i have checked it already. Hopefully one of app launched ok

Comment: First, check the applicationId in `build.gradle`. Then check package line in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Then check your package hierarchy in the project. They should be the same. If not, you need to change it according to the package hierarchy

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך im trying to like it shows on stack but it doesn't work. Don't know why

Comment: What is the stack tells?